# Update attributes rails - No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to basically update my integration object attribute "filters". I have a integrations controller and what seems the proper actions to do so. But when I try to save after filling out the text-field I get this error `No route matches [POST]`, I understand what it's saying but isn't update a post? Here is my code for clarity.

### Controller

```
    def update
    @integrations = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])

    attrs = params.require(:integration).permit(:filters)

    if @integrations.update_attributes(attrs)
      redirect_to account_integration_path
    else
      render :filters
    end
  end

  def filters
    @integrations = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])
  end
```

### View

```
    <%= form_for @integrations, url: filters_account_integration_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :filters, class: "tag-autocomplete" %>
    <%= link_to "Save", account_integration_path, method: :post, class: [ "button", "button--modal" ] %>
    <% end %>
```

### Routes

```
   resources :integrations, only: [ :index, :destroy, :update ] do
    get "filters", on: :member
   end
```

Hopefully that is enough info let me know if you need more? My basic question is why is this not updating the integration object? Isn't update a post?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has something do with this but.. you are using both a get and post method in your form, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources` generates seven routes by default. You're using it to generate only three of those. Those three routes will look like this:

- `GET /integrations`
- `DELETE /integrations/:id`
- `PATCH /integrations/:id/edit`

Your form, on the other hand, is trying to use this route:

- `POST /integrations/:id`

which doesn't match any of the generated routes.

Instead, try using the default form helpers:

```
<%= form_for @integrations, url: url_for(:controller => :integrations, :action => :update, :id => @integrations.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :filters, class: "tag-autocomplete" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

That's assuming that `@integrations` is a single `Integration` resource. If it isn't, you have bigger problems than just this.